# Why can't a left-recursive, non-deterministic, or ambiguous grammar be LL(1)?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars

I've learned from several sources that an LL(1) grammar is:

1. unambiguous,
2. not left-recursive,
3. and, deterministic (left-factorized).

What I can't fully understand is why the above is true for any LL(1) grammar. I know the LL(1) parsing table will have multiple entries at some cells, but what I really want to get is a formal and general (not with an example) proof to the following proposition(s):

A left-recursive (1), non-deterministic (2), or ambiguous (3) grammar is not LL(1).

Comment: I don't know what `left-factored' means, but Corollary 5.41 of Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen's _Parsing Theory_ answers (1) and Theorem 5.37 of the same answers (3) for any SLL(k) grammar, while Lemma 8.39 shows that any LL(1) grammar is SLL(1).

Comment: @Sylvain Thanks for the references, and by 'left-factored' I mean 'deterministic grammar', e.g., `S->aB|aC` is not left-factored, `S->aS'` ;; `S' -> B|C` is left-factored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some more research, and I think I've found a solution for the 1st and 2nd questions, as for the 3rd one, I found an existing solution on StackOverflow for it, the proof attempts are written below:

We start by writing the three rules of the definition of an LL(1) grammar:

For every production `A -> α | β` with `α ≠ β`:

1. `FIRST(α) ∩ FIRST(β) = Ø`.
2. If `β =>* ε` then `FIRST(α) ∩ FOLLOW(A) = Ø` (also, if `α =>* ε` then `FIRST(β) ∩ FOLLOW(A) = Ø`).
3. Including `ε` in rule (1) implies that at most one of `α` and `β` can derive `ε`.

**Proposition 1:** *A non-factored grammar is not LL(1).*

**Proof:**

If a grammar G is non-factored then there exists a production in G of the form:

```
A -> ωα1 | ωα2 | ... | ωαn
```

(where `αi` is the `i-th α`, not the symbols `α` and `i`), with `α1 ≠ α2 ≠ ... ≠ αn`. We can then easily show that:

```
∩(i=1,..,n) FIRST(ωαi) ≠ Ø
```

which contradicts rule (1) of the definition, thus, a non-factored grammar is not LL(1). ∎

**Proposition 2:** *A left-recursive grammar is not LL(1).*

**Proof:**

If a grammar is left-recursive then there exists a production in G of the form:

```
S -> Sα | β
```

Three cases arise here:

1. If `FIRST(β) ≠ {ε}` then:

   `FIRST(β) ⊆ FIRST(S)`

   `=>  FIRST(β) ∩ FIRST(Sα) ≠ Ø`

   which contradicts rule (1) of the definition.
2. If `FIRST(β) = {ε}` then:

   2.1. If `ε ∈ FIRST(α)` then:

   `ε ∈ FIRST(Sα)`

   which contradicts rule (3) of the definition.

   2.2. If `ε ∉ FIRST(α)` then:

   `FIRST(α) ⊆ FIRST(S)` (because `β =>* ε`)

   `=>  FIRST(α) ⊆ FIRST(Sα) ........ (I)`

   we also know that:

   `FIRST(α) ⊆ FOLLOW(S) ........ (II)`

   by `(I)` and `(II)`, we have:

   `FIRST(Sα) ∩ FOLLOW(S) ≠ Ø`

   and since `β =>* ε`, this contradicts rule (2) of the definition.

In every case we arrive at a contradiction, hence, a left-recursive grammar is not LL(1). ∎

**Proposition 3:** *An ambiguous grammar is not LL(1).*

**Proof:**

While the above proofs are mine, this one is not, it's by [Kevin A. Naudé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588948/kevin-a-naud%C3%A9) which I got from his answer that is linked below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969767/6275103